# Filter users by attribute

Tags: c#, active-directory

This gives a list of UserPrincipals from our ActiveDirectory where Users are in group "x":

```
var domainContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
var groupPrincipal = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domainContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, "x");
```

Now how would I filter the users in this list by a custom attribute? All users have an entry in the custom property "Building", and I want to the list to contain only users from a certain building.

**SOLUTION**

stupid me ... cast the members from groupPrincipal to DirectoryEntry, then access properties ..

```
        foreach (var member in groupPrincipal.Members)
        {
            // maybe some try-catch ..
            System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry i = (System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry)member.GetUnderlyingObject();
            if (i.Properties["building"].Value.toString() == "NSA HQ")
            {
                // Do stuff here
            }

        }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151770/retrieve-ad-custom-attribute-in-one-batch may help.

Comment: thanks, I've edited my question .. post as answer and I'll vote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you may use member.GetUnderlyingObject()

```
var members = groupPrincipal.Members.Where(member=>(member.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry).Properties["building"].Value.ToString() == "NSA HQ");
```

as pointed out in [Retrieve AD Custom Attribute in One Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151770/retrieve-ad-custom-attribute-in-one-batch)